# @SmallTest, @MediumTest, and @LargeTest deprecated on Android

Tags: android

These 3 annotations `@SmallTest`, `@MediumTest`, and `@LargeTest` has been recently deprecated on Android.

But I couldn't find any documentation which explains the motivation or proposes a new annotation set.

So, is there any way right now for declaring the scope of a test?

Answer (score 26):

Previously these annotations were in the `android.test.suitebuilder.annotation` package. As of API 24, they were moved to the `android.support.test.filters` package (documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/suitebuilder/annotation/MediumTest.html) for `@MediumTest`. `@SmallTest` and `@LargeTest` are the same).

To use the new versions:

1. Be sure you're using `import android.support.test.filters.<size>Test` at the top of your test file.
2. Ensure your test `runner` and `rules` versions are using at least version 0.5 in your `build.gradle` file:

   `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'`

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm already using 0.5 version for both rules and runner but it isn't able to resolve such package. Could you please share a complete gradle configuration dependency block in order to check with my current configuration?

Comment: Are you 1000% sure your import statements are correct? They should be pointing to `import android.support.test.filters.<size>Test`.

Comment: Yes. It can't resolve "android.support.test.filters" package.

Comment: I have the same issue as @VíctorAlbertos

Comment: Alright I figure it out, its because `<size>Test` is actually meant for instrumentation test. It will only show `*` when intellisensing the import if you are getting `<size>Test`  in the test folder (not the androidTest folder).

Comment: Just a note that the latest Android X dependencies are `androidx.test:runner` and `androidx.annotation:annotation`

Answer (score 10):

**Update for androidx**

dependency declared in app's `build.gradle`:

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'`

and then imports looks like:

```
import androidx.test.filters.SmallTest;
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.filters.FlakyTest;
```

**Original answer**:

Like Chris said, they are moved in the [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html) as of API 24 (apps targeting this api onwards)

In order to use the annotations for JUnit/Unit tests you have to add:

```
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

in your `build.gradle` file

and for UI/instrumentation tests add:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

Then in your test class add one/more of the following imports:

```
import android.support.test.filters.SmallTest;
import android.support.test.filters.MediumTest;
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
import android.support.test.filters.FlakyTest;
```

Comment: I have `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'` and AS cannot resolve `import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;`

Comment: Are you using maybe this import in a unit test instead (class file under src/test) ? Because if so, then you need to use the `testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'`

If you are not sure, give me the full path of your class file where you are using the import.

Comment: testCompile is deprecated on new Gradle

Comment: I am trying to use `@SmallTest` and found out that `androidx.test:runner` needs to be added which also solves another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78076465/12204620) of mine trying to run instrumented test in an Android module but fails. Two birds in one stone!

Answer (score 5):

Update for **androidx**

**Step 1**: In your app's build.gradle file, inside dependencies add:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
```

**Step 2**: In your test class, add the needed imports

```
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest;
import androidx.test.filters.SmallTest;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** In your app's `build.gradle` file, inside `dependencies` add:

```
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

**Please note that**: You have to add this line as `testImplementation`, not `androidTestImplementation`

**Step 2:** In your test class, add one/more of the following imports (Based on your need)

```
import android.support.test.filters.SmallTest;
import android.support.test.filters.MediumTest;
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
```